# How to fix flaking paint on a deck railing and make it last?

Tags: paint, deck, outdoor

Well, two years ago I painted my deck railing and now it looks like this.

[image]
(Peeling and flaking off)

My instinct is to sand it down with a random-orbital sander and then a wire brush and repaint, but I suspect this won't be good enough.  How do I paint over this to make it last?

Comment: Did you prime it? Did you use an outdoor-rated paint?

Comment: Yes, the paint was high quality indoor-outdoor paint.  I did not prime; I thought that paint itself was a good primer on bare wood.  I did three coats.  Was that a mistake?

Answer (score 2):

Scrape, sand, prime and then paint with exterior grade products. Longevity of the paint will also be based on the moisture content of the wood at the time you painted it. A handy 'mini-Ligno' moisture meter is used to determine if the wood is dry enough to hold primer and paint. Consult with the paint manufacturer for moisture content recommendations.

See... Mini-Ligno    http://www.lignomatusa.com/meters/mini-ligno-md/
Long lasting paint... http://www.paintpro.net/Articles/PP503/PP503_CoatingsFailure.cfm

Comment: Are you saying "scrape and sand" down to nothing?  In other words, start over?

Comment: No. You need to remove debris from years of use and any loose paint. Then prime and paint. This link may best suit you by Benjamin Moore paints...  http://www.benjaminmoore.com/en-us/for-your-home/exterior-painting

Comment: ok, so paint that looks good, I should just prime and re-paint?

Comment: What I mean to ask is: do I prime and paint over the remaining paint, or do I paint without primer there?

Comment: I wish I understood this better. I did all this two years ago and now it's back to peeling just like the photos above.

Comment: And today it's even worse.  Any further suggestions for me?

Comment: @Patrick, the wood swells and contracts with moisture content over time. Ponded water isn't good. Moisture content also tracks relative humidity, NOT DEW POINT. 90% humidity implies 20% moisture content and 65% humidity implies 12% moisture content. See page 316 from https://www.fpl.fs.usda.gov/documnts/fplgtr/fplgtr282/fpl_gtr282.pdf for major US city month-to-month humidity. Exterior grade paint, then, has to be more stretchy than interior grade paint. UV resistance also affects longevity. Primer enhances adhesion, but needs the stretchiness too.

Answer (score 1):

I used Sherwin Williams exterior deck and floor enamel on our front porch..I primed it first with a water based spar varnish..It has been four years and it has not peeled..I used to have to repaint it every year..